# Filling gridview from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, sqldatasource

I have a gridview control in my ASP.NET web form. I the past I have used the same code to fill a gridview with data in a Windows Forms App.

Here is my code:

```
var sql = new SQL_Statements();
var stringSql = "select col1, col2, col3, col4 from table1 where col5=" + stringPO_NUM;
var sql_ds = sql.SelectFromDB(stringSql);
int DataIndex;
if (sql_ds.Tables["CurData"].Rows.Count > 0)
    for (DataIndex = 0; DataIndex <= sql_ds.Tables["CurData"].Rows.Count - 1; DataIndex++)
    {
        sql_ds.Tables["CurData"].Rows[DataIndex]["col4"].ToString();
        //Fill the datagridview with the data that was just pulled from SQL_Statements
        GV_POI.DataSource = sql_ds;
        GV_POI.DataMember = "CurData";
    }
```

Here is the code for the SelectFromDB:

```
public DataSet SelectFromDB(String Sql)
        {
            var functionReturnValue = default(DataSet);
            var Class_Connection = new SQL_Connection();
            Class_Connection.cnn.Close(); //Let's close the connection, just in case it is open
            Class_Connection.cnn.Open();                
            var myDataAdaptor = new SqlDataAdapter(Sql, Class_Connection.cnn);
            var myDataset = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                myDataAdaptor.SelectCommand.Connection = Class_Connection.cnn;
                myDataAdaptor.SelectCommand.CommandText = Sql;
                myDataAdaptor.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                myDataAdaptor.Fill(myDataset, "CurData");
                functionReturnValue = myDataset;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                Class_Connection.cnn.Close();
            }
            return functionReturnValue;
            Class_Connection.cnn.Close();
        }
```

Here is the code for the GridView in the ASPX page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV_POI" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        </asp:GridView>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. When the page loads, the gridview is blank. I checked the code in the debugger, and code is firing. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is col5 a character or numeric type? Shouldn't you be using a parameter to set that value in any case?

Comment: @rontornambe col5 is numeric

Comment: Have you checked postback? `if(!Page.IsPostBack) { CallBindFunction(); }`

Comment: @HassanNisar No. The code was fired in the Page_LoadComplete, I checked in the debugger

Comment: check `@Lorin's` answer I think you are missing `GV_POI.DataBind();`

Comment: Seeing your comment to @meda, have you made sure sql_ds actually contains data and not just 1 row with null or blank data?

Comment: What do you think that `sql_ds.Tables["CurData"].Rows[DataIndex]["col4"].ToString();` does?

Comment: @sr28 Yes I just doubled checked. sql_ds has data from the table.

Comment: Can you show the code of your datagrid?

Comment: @sr28 How so? Do you mean in the UI of the control?

Comment: As in what's the code you've got in the asp.net page for the datagrid? Something like <asp:DataGrid ID="GV_POI" runat="server">Your columns here...</asp:DataGrid>

Comment: @sr28 I updated the question with the gridview code

Comment: I've updated my previous answer. I think it's because you're not specifying the columns and have 'AutoGenerateColumns' set to 'false'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting all data in  dataset "sql_ds" then there is no need of for loop ,
you can do as below

```
GV_POI.DataSource = sql_ds.Tables[0];
GV_POI.DataBind();
```

and also either make  AutoGenerateColumns="True" or use
BoundField or TemplateField.

Example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTest" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="Vertical"
     OnRowEditing="gvTests_RowEditing"  AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20"
     OnRowDataBound="gvTest_RowDataBound">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidecss" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidecss" >
      <ItemStyle Width="80px" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
      <HeaderStyle Width="80px" Wrap="False" />
</asp:BoundField>                           
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name">
      <ItemStyle Width="200px" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
      <HeaderStyle Width="200px" Wrap="False" />
</asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Description" DataField="Description">
      <ItemStyle Width="200px" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
      <HeaderStyle Width="200px" Wrap="False" />
</asp:BoundField>                          
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" EditImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" ButtonType="Image">
      <HeaderStyle Width="20px" />
      <ItemStyle Width="20px" />
</asp:CommandField>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete"
      ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png" AlternateText="Delete"
      ToolTip="Click to Delete"></asp:ImageButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderCss" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="PagerCss" />                        
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AltRowCss" />
    <EditRowStyle CssClass="EditRowCss" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I didn't see a property called BoundField or TemplateField

Comment: @nate i have edited my answer with example for BoundField, CommandField & TemplateField.

Answer (score 0):

Well it appears to me you are binding GV_POI to a string

```
var stringSql = "select col1, col2, col3, col4 from table1 where col5=" + stringPO_NUM;
GV_POI.DataSource = stringSql;
```

Not an actual list of data.

I think you wanted

```
GV_POI.DataSource = sql_ds;
```

Comment: That is how it is coded, it was a typeo, sorry about that. I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do the following where you're currently setting the datamember as it looks like you're currently not binding the data to the datagrid:

```
string member;
member = "CurData";
GV_POI.SetDataBinding(sql_ds, member);
```

***EDIT*** - following update:

If you've set 'AutoGenerateColumns' to 'false' then you need to specify the columns. An example would be:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateColumn>
        <HeaderTemplate>Job Number</HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Job Number") %></ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
</Columns>
```

Obviously you might want to simply do a 'BoundColumn' or something similar. You'd also need to substitute in your own header data etc. You'd need to do this for every column you want to display basically. Alternatively, just set 'AutoGenerateColumns' to 'true'.

Comment: Ok, seeing as you're only returning 1 table of data anyway in your dataset then you can use GV_POI.DataBind().

Comment: I just tried that at the end of the loop. The gridview still is blank

Comment: @nate I see you marked an answer for this. Did you try my suggestion in my edit done way before the marked answer?

Comment: I am looking @ your edit now. And to answer your question, no I didn't since gmd answered the question hours before your edit.

Comment: @nate I appreciate you looking at my edit. It would be good to know what the issue was. As for the timing of the answers my edit was done 23 hours ago (at the time of this comment) and the marked answer was done 21 hours ago...

Answer (score 0):

You should set the DataSource property and then Bind it. Good Example can be found there:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

```
  DataSet ds = GetData(queryString);
  if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
  {
    AuthorsGridView.DataSource = ds;
    AuthorsGridView.DataBind();
  }
```

Comment: Still can't resolve symbol GetData or AuthorsGridView

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the loop don't forget to `databind()`

```
GV_POI.DataBind();
```

Comment: Tried that, and the gridview is still blank

Comment: @nate please show `SelectFromDB` it should return a dataTable

Answer (score 0):

If you tried `GV_POI.DataBind()` appended to your code, and that didn't work, then I would look at what event is triggering your code to execute.  Is it the Page Load event?  Also check to see if you have any `GV_POI` events that could be over-writing your data binding event?  For example `GV_POI_DataBound` or `GV_POI_RowDataBound`?

Answer (score 0):

There u go:

```
    public DataTable SelectFromDB(String Sql)
    {

        var Class_Connection = new SQL_Connection();

        Class_Connection.cnn.Open();                
        var myDataAdaptor = new SqlDataAdapter(Sql, Class_Connection.cnn);
        var myDataTable = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            myDataAdaptor.SelectCommand.Connection = Class_Connection.cnn;
            myDataAdaptor.SelectCommand.CommandText = Sql;
            myDataAdaptor.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            myDataAdaptor.Fill(myDataTable);
            Class_Connection.cnn.Close(); 
            return myDataTable;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            Class_Connection.cnn.Close();
            return null;
        }
    }


var sql = new SQL_Statements();
var stringSql = "select col1, col2, col3, col4 from table1 where col5=" + stringPO_NUM;
var sql_ds = sql.SelectFromDB(stringSql);

GV_POI.DataSource = sql_ds;
GV_POI.DAtaBind();


<asp:GridView ID="GV_POI" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>No records registered</EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Get Your data in DataTable and than

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    grid.DataSource = dt;
    gridDataBind();
}
```